# In java, is it possible to save a variable, local to a thread?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to do some logging from a servlet based java app, using log4j.  I'd like to log extra information like user id etc. Is there any way to put local variables in a thread? and while logging, is it possible to get the current thread, and get the set local variable?

Comment: Can u past your log4j config, then i will show u how to add the thread name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than using thread local storage directly, use Log4j's [NDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html) and [MDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) (nested and mapped diagnostic contexts). They are already thread-local and you can include their data in log messages using the `%x` and `%X` patterns so there's no need to explicitly pull the data out of the thread local context to include it in the log message.

Answer (score 6):

**Log4J MDC approach**

This is how to do it with MDC

```
public class MdcExample implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger logger  = Logger.getLogger(MdcExample.class);

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final MdcExample threadLocalExample = new MdcExample();

        final Thread thread1 = new Thread(threadLocalExample);
        final Thread thread2 = new Thread(threadLocalExample);
        final Thread thread3 = new Thread(threadLocalExample);

        thread1.start(); thread2.start(); thread3.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            MDC.put("random", "" + Math.random());

            try {
                logger.info("My log message, prefixed with MDC");
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            }
            catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Log4J settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %X{random}:- %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender> 

    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

**Thread Local approach (if your Businesslogic requires it)**

If you like to store values (like users) locally to a thread, then use `ThreadLocal`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadLocalExample implements Runnable {
    ThreadLocal<Double> myRandom    = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ThreadLocalExample threadLocalExample = new ThreadLocalExample();

        final Thread thread1 = new Thread(threadLocalExample);
        final Thread thread2 = new Thread(threadLocalExample);
        final Thread thread3 = new Thread(threadLocalExample);

        thread1.start(); thread2.start(); thread3.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        this.myRandom.set(Math.random());

        while (true) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + this.myRandom.get());

            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            }
            catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

**Adding the Thread ID to log4j output**

Regarding your log4j question, you can use th `t`-Placeholder for the Thread name:

This is an example Appender you can use:

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

Comment: @user187809 Do you need smth. else?

Answer (score 3):

`ThreadLocal` is the way to go. `ThreadLocal` offers functionality to save variables which are not shared across the threads and are are available throughout the life of thread.

`ThreadLocal` by very nature of this functionality help you to get rid of synchronize blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [MDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) for this. You can store named properties and then refer to them directly in your log formats. See [What is the difference between Log4j's NDC and MDC facilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134734/log4j-ndc-vs-mdc-difference) for an example.

Comment: This looks neat, as I don't have to append any string to my logging functions !! I'm searching for a full example of using MDC, do you know of any tutorial/example? Thank You.

Comment: [Mapped Diagnostic Context](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) explains it in the context of slf4j, with examples.