# Add ${xd.job.name} and ${xd.stream.name} to Spring XD logs

Tags: logging, spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-xd

We are running several streams and jobs on Spring XD v1.0.0.RELEASE.
The corresponding stream and job modules log messages to Spring XD's global log files, under **$XD_HOME/logs**
We need to tell apart log messages created by each job and stream. Tagging each log line with the value of **${xd.job.name}** or **${xd.stream.name}** should work for us. For example,

1) In a config file (Spring XD config, XML context file, Java class... whatever), set a Java context(?) variable:

```
if(moduleType == "job") {
  name = ${xd.job.name};
} else if(moduleType == "stream") {
  name = ${xd.stream.name};
} else {
  name = "XD";
}
```

2) Configure log4j properties files under **$XD_HOME/config** accordingly:

```
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2} [${name}] - %m%n
```

3) Log output for Spring XD running a job (xd.job.name = "**fooJob**") and a stream (xd.stream.name = "**barStream**"):

```
...
13:07:41,169  DEBUG task-scheduler-1 myjobimpl.TransactionManager [fooJob] - Initiating transaction commit
...
13:08:43,215  INFO task-scheduler-15 mystreamimpl.JsonDecoder [barStream] - Decoding JSON: {...}
...
14:08:42,569  INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter [XD] - Summary on shutdown: MessageChannelMonitor: [name=input, sends=0]
```

4) Any message logged by other libraries (e.g. Spring Data, Apache Commons, whatever) should have one of [**fooJob**], [**barStream**] or [**XD**], same value as the job or stream that invoked the library.

The **only** half-baked solution we came up so far is setting **$name** in log4j's [MDC or NDC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134734/what-is-the-difference-between-log4js-ndc-and-mdc-facilities), but we don't know how to set it on a per-stream or per-job basis (MDC and NDC work on a per-thread basis).

Is there any way to add job or stream name to their corresponding log lines?

Answer (score 0):

We were talking about this internally after seeing your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636024/stream-and-job-analytics-from-spring-xds-logfile).

We also discussed the MDC, which we could set up in the bus implementations but it would only work for processors and sinks. We'd need code in Spring Integration/Spring Batch to make it work for sources and jobs as well.

It would also be overhead that many wouldn't want so it would have to be optional.

Bottom line is we don't have a solution (yet), but feel free to open up a new feature [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD).

**EDIT:** Responding to your comment below...

Hmmmm... for processors and sinks you could add a `ChannelInterceptor` to the `input` channel and push the name in `preSend()` and pop it in `postSend()`. For sources you could do the same on the `output` channel.

The only problem with that is that `postSend()` is not called if an exception is thrown after `preSend()`. Spring Integration 4.1 (should be released next week; currently available as a [release candidate](https://spring.io/blog/2014/10/27/spring-integration-4-1-rc1-released)) [adds support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/134aa5923e58df69867532ab3965e15e183e5a62#diff-1) for calling `interceptor.afterSendCompletion()` which is called regardless of whether an exception occurred or not.

Note: when getting a reference to the channel, to add the interceptor, you have to do it using `ChannelInterceptorAware` because the bean might be proxied.

If this works, and you would like to [contribute it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) we'd be happy to consider it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was thinking of creating a XD Plugin that modifies (AOP?) each bean of a Module context (stream or job), by adding a before and after advice to each method of each bean. They should execute **NDC.push($name)** and **NDC.pop()** respectively. When running a stream or job, every time a bean method begins or ends, its thread gets "tagged" or "untagged", and so will the corresponding log messages. I don't know if it's even possible and IMO it's an ugly hack. Can you provide some help?

Comment: Thanks again, yours looks like a much better solution for streams and maybe something along these lines could work for jobs, too ;-)

Comment: hmmmm.... this gets even more tricky when you get into reactor-based stream processors (basically anything wrapped by [BroadcasterMessageHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/xd/reactor/BroadcasterMessageHandler.html)). The code runs in a separate thread, so MDC/NDC probably won't work. We're trying to figure out a solution as well...

Answer (score 0):

I end up creating a custom Logback [formatting converter](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/pattern/FormattingConverter.html).

```
public class SpringPropertyConverter extends ClassicConverter {

    private String key;
    private String defaultValue = "";

    @Override
    public void start() {
        String[] keyInfo = extractDefaultReplacement(getFirstOption());
        key = keyInfo[0];
        if (keyInfo[1] != null) {
            defaultValue = keyInfo[1];
        }
        super.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        key = null;
        super.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public String convert(ILoggingEvent event) {
        SpringLogbackPropertyResolver resolver = SpringLogbackPropertyResolver.getInstance();
        if (resolver == null) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        return resolver.getProperty(key, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Backed by a bean holding the `Environment` instance:

```
@Service
public class SpringLogbackPropertyResolver {

    private static volatile SpringLogbackPropertyResolver instance;

    private final Environment env;
    private final Map<String, String> map;

    public SpringLogbackPropertyResolver(@Autowired Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
        this.map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        this.instance = this;
    }

    public String getProperty(String key, String defaultValue){
        return map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> env.getProperty(key, defaultValue));
    }

    public static SpringLogbackPropertyResolver getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Then in `xd-container-logback.groovy` the converter is registered:

```
conversionRule("spring", SpringPropertyConverter)
```

It could then be used in the log pattern with the `spring` prefix `%spring{xd.stream.name:-bar}`