# How to get the folder where log4j logs are being written to?

Tags: java, log4j

Sometimes when I want to log diagnostic details about an error the amount of data is quite large.  What I would like to do is make a regular log entry with the name of a file that would also appear in the log directory that would contain all this extra data.

This is not just another log, there would be one file per log entry.  About 1% of my log entries involve several KB of diagnostic data - I want to put each one of those in a separate file and put the name of that file in the regular log for reference.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to create a logger which logs just the information sent by a certain package (which is that creating the diagnostic data) ? This would save all into one file, but you could use MDC to mark which belongs to what occurence of the error.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the MDC approach or point me to appropriate resources.  Up till now I have only had to deal with basic logging - simple small messages and stack traces - so my knowledge of Log4j is limited.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134734/what-is-the-difference-between-log4js-ndc-and-mdc-facilities

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a try...